# Incorrect timezone getting punched into db

Tags: postgresql, datetime, heroku, flask

I have created table that has column with dateTime with timezone.
In my *model.py*:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Messages(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'
    msgId = db.Column('msg_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullName = db.Column(db.String(60))
    message = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    visitorId = db.Column(db.String(10))
    done = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    pub_date = db.Column(types.Time(timezone=True)) 

    def __init__(self, fullName, email, message, visitorId, submitTime):
        self.fullName = fullName
        self.email = email
        self.message = message
        self.visitorId = visitorId
        self.done = False
        self.pub_date = submitTime
```

And I have created table using `db.create_all()` on `heroku pg:psql` that resulted below:

```
DATABASE=> \d messages
                                    Table "public.messages"
  Column   |         Type          |                         Modifiers                         
-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 msg_id    | integer               | not null default nextval('messages_msg_id_seq'::regclass)
 fullName  | character varying(60) | 
 message   | character varying     | 
 email     | character varying     | 
 visitorId | character varying(10) | 
 done      | boolean               | 
 pub_date  | time with time zone   |
```

No matter what timezone/date time I am using the timezone seems to getting punched `+00` which is UTC.

```
4 | ciasto       | testing    |          | 9IQVW1K6W | f    | 15:48:31.784704+00
```

why is this happening?

I am passing the time as using the below routing function which should be passing correct `dtWithZone` from below to postgreSQL's table messages `pub_date`

```
@app.route('/newmsg', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newmsg():
    form = _appforms.MessagingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = request.form['fullName']
        ip = request.access_route[0] # gives ip address of the visitor
        unique_visitor_id = request.cookies.get("unique_visitor")

        data = _utils.getJsonFromURL("http://ip-api.com/json/{}".format(ip))
        tz = "Asia/Kolkata"
        if data["status"] == "success":
            tz = data["timezone"]

        flash("Your IP is {} and you are visiting this site from {} timezone.".format(ip, tz))

        dtWithZone = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(tz))
        msg = Messages(name, request.form['email'], request.form['message'], unique_visitor_id, dtWithZone)
        _db.session.add(msg)
        _db.session.commit()
        msg = "Thank you, {}".format(name)
        return render_template('thankyou.html', form=form, msg=msg)
    return render_template('newMessage.html', form=form, title=" | Messaging", msg="Write your message")
```

However this is working correctly on my local computer and looking at table entry I can see:

```
  8 | tester | local teasing   |         | NV33A1L66 | f  | 21:09:24.804903+05:30
```

Comment: Not MySQL. Removed tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a short tutorial on timezones for ya. To see what timezones postgresql has in its internal tz database, run this query:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names ;
(edited list)
               name               | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
----------------------------------+--------+------------+--------
 America/Denver                   | MDT    | -06:00:00  | t
 America/Phoenix                  | MST    | -07:00:00  | f
 America/New_York                 | EDT    | -04:00:00  | t
 America/Chicago                  | CDT    | -05:00:00  | t
 America/Los_Angeles              | PDT    | -07:00:00  | t
```

And here's an example of setting tz and inserting timestamps:

```
create table tztest (ts timestamptz, tz text);
set timezone="America/New_York";
insert into tztest values ('2017-01-10 12:00:00','America/New_York');
set timezone='America/Chicago';
insert into tztest values ('2017-01-10 12:00:00','America/Chicago');
set timezone='America/Denver';
insert into tztest values ('2017-01-10 12:00:00','America/Denver');
set timezone='America/Phoenix';
insert into tztest values ('2017-01-10 12:00:00','America/Phoenix');
set timezone='America/Los_Angeles';
insert into tztest values ('2017-01-10 12:00:00','America/Los_Angeles')
select * from tztest ;
           ts           |         tz
------------------------+---------------------
 2017-01-10 09:00:00-08 | America/New_York
 2017-01-10 10:00:00-08 | America/Chicago
 2017-01-10 11:00:00-08 | America/Denver
 2017-01-10 11:00:00-08 | America/Phoenix
 2017-01-10 12:00:00-08 | America/Los_Angeles
```

Note that while LA is listed as having a -07:00:00 offset, it's not summer, so right now it's -08:00:00 for dates January.

To see the actual stored timestamps, set the timezone to UTC:

```
set timezone='UTC';
select * from tztest ;
           ts           |         tz
------------------------+---------------------
 2017-01-10 17:00:00+00 | America/New_York
 2017-01-10 18:00:00+00 | America/Chicago
 2017-01-10 19:00:00+00 | America/Denver
 2017-01-10 19:00:00+00 | America/Phoenix
 2017-01-10 20:00:00+00 | America/Los_Angeles
```

Comment: Any time! Timezone math is rather quirky, so it's something I always let the db handle if possible.

Comment: having another column just to store timezone doesnt hurt so I added a new column just to store user timezone in my project.

Answer (score 1):

**Figured out myself** `, since PostgreSQL timezone aware, if we punch datetime with timezone it converts it to PostgreSQL local timezone , so on heroku it is set to UTC so it was always getting converted to UTC format, so I converted the column pub_date to db.String(24) and saving date/time/ with timezone as string. which works perfect.`

**Updated message:**

First define table that has column which accepts datetime with timezone:

**src/model.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import DateTime

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Messages(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'
    msgId = db.Column('msg_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullName = db.Column(db.String(60))
    message = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    visitorId = db.Column(db.String(10))
    done = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    pub_date = db.Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
```

then from python terminal: run `from src.model import db; db.create_all()`
this will create the table in the postgresql with proper column type/ name.
then have a below function that connects to postgresSQL with user timezone :

```
def insertIntoTable(dtWithZone, tableName, columValues):
    db_uri = "postgresql://localhost/messages"
    engine = create_engine(db_uri, connect_args={"options": "-c timezone={}".format(dtWithZone.timetz().tzinfo.zone)})
    meta = MetaData(engine, reflect=True)
    table = meta.tables[tableName]
    ins = table.insert().values(**columValues)
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(ins)
    conn.close()
```

thats it !

now from the routing function I did the following changes:

```
@app.route('/newmsg', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newmsg():
    form = _appforms.MessagingForm()
    # if form.validate_on_submit():
    if request.method == "POST":
        ip = request.access_route[0]
        data = _utils.getJsonFromURL("http://ip-api.com/json/{}".format(ip))
        tz = "Pacific/America"
        if data["status"] == "success":
            tz = data.get("timezone")

        dtWithZone = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(tz))
        name = request.form.get('fullName', "")
        columValues = {
        'pub_date' : dtWithZone,  
        'fullName' : name,
        'visitorId': request.cookies.get("unique_visitor", ""),
        'message' : request.form.get('message', ""),
        'email' : request.form.get('email', "")
        }

        insertIntoTable(dtWithZone, 'messages', columValues)
        msg = "Thank you, {}".format(name)
        return render_template('thankyou.html', form=form, msg=msg)
    return render_template('newMessage.html', form=form, title=" | Messaging", msg="Write your message")
```

works perfect (y)

Comment: You can also set timezone per connection, which will override postgresql's internal timezone. Also also you can do "at time zone tznamehere" to say what timezone it's in.

Handling date/time stamps in text is a great way to get things wrong due to shifting timezone offsets like daylight savings time etc.

Comment: You mean to say for each connection I execute a query `SET TIMEZONE TO 'time zone of the user';` ?

Comment: You can also do stuff like alter user, alter database, etc to make such things stick.

Comment: Note that it is helpful to store the timezone of the user somewhere as well. Just that letting the db do the timezone work and know the tz it came from. Internally pg always stores timestamps with tz as utc.

Comment: Albeit, since I am using SQLAchemy as an ORM for my flask app . Is it a good approach to set the time zone in connection like this from my flask app `engine = create_engine("...", connect_args={"options": "-c timezone=user_timezone"})`

Comment: Yeah that works. Note that if you want, you can connect, get the timezone that you've stored for a particular user, then reconnect with it in that string. But if mostly you already know the timezone then skip that and just set it on connect.

Comment: Or connect, get a tz for user, then set time zone in line.

Comment: @Scott Marlowe : I got success , however i was creating `pub_date` column based on `types.time(timezone=True)` which creates column that does not takes date . Can you show me how in sqlalchemy I can create column that stores dateTime with time zone ?

Comment: I'd try types.timestamp but I know nothing of sqlalchemy.

Comment: No Worries I got it with : `db.Column(DateTime(timezone=True)) `

Comment: Now you may choose to up vote my answer (y) if agree with it.

Comment: I checked again, and it seems on heroku it is still punching timezone to utc not the user timezone I am passing

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. Internally timestamptz is always stored as UTC, and timezone adjustment provided on the into and out of the database.

Comment: Set timezone = <yourtimezonehere> plus you can permaset it for a db (alter database ...) or a user (alter user ...) So after setting your timeszone to say US/Pacific, you insert a timestamp it will get adjusted by x hours (whatever the offset) and stored as UTC. Then if you set your timezone to US/NewYork, and retrieve it, you'll get a different time, since the offset is smaller now.